# Javascript: Text in arrays and multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to load a parent page into an object tag, and whilst I can get an alert to show I've got the code, I cannot get it into the <object> Any clues?

```
    var page=parent.document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    alert(page);
    document.getElementById('close_skin').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('show_skin').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('show_skin').setAttribute("data",page);
```

Assuming I can get the code to appear, how can I "toggle" to a different set of styles? The parent uses ".xxx_fixed" classes, but the code in the object needs to use the ".xxx_float" classes that are also in the template CSS at top of page. (When I did it in another PERL program, it was easy just to rename the tags in the <body> from "class='xxx_fixed' " to "class='xxx_float' " (Can't do that so easily with global javascript replace as that would also rename the classes at top of code as well!)

I have just tried adding some script to the top of the var page object - which MAY work if I can get the code to appear ...

```
    +'document.getElementById(\'icon_outer\').setAttribute(\'class\', \'icon_outer_float\')'
```

If you're interested as to the "why", the "fixed" keep menu / top bar fixed in one place when viewed in full screen browser, but the 'float' makes everything move in unison within the <object> "window" allowing viewer to pan around the template page like a static magnifying glass;

```
    .menu_back_float{position:relative;top:0px;background-color:#f5eca4;min-height:520px;height:auto}
    .menu_back_fixed{position:relative;top:35px;background-color:#f5eca4;min-height:550px;height:auto}
```

Comment: Sorry it's taken me ages to get around to replying. (I should have specified I didn't want to use JQuery; I'm only just about getting to grips with javascript and CSS and don't want to add another language to the mix)

If you're interested in what I came up with, you can take a look at my "Skin Designer". A well versed programmer will probably find it crude to the extreme, but hey, it works: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q814lbnv8dco8eo/SkinDesigner.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

To load the parent page into an `<object>` element, you have to specify the URL of the page. To get the code and place it in a alert box, you can use jQuery's `$.get()` method (as long as you load it via a proxy domain), like this:

HTML:

```
// I'm just using W3Schools just to save time
<object data="http://www.w3schools.com/" width="1500" height="1200">
     <embed src="http://www.w3schools.com/" width="1500" height="1200"></embed>
     Your browser does not support the object tag.
</object>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.jQuery.get("http://www.yourdomain.com/?url=www.w3schools.com", function(response) {
   window.alert(response);
}
```

For the second part of your question, you can use jQuery to change the name of the class from `.xxx_fixed` to `.xxx_float`:

```
function main() {
    $('object').removeClass('xxx_fixed').addClass('xxx_float');
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Hopefully I have answered your question correctly and thouroughly, and if I haven't, feel free to let me know so I can edit this.